# Tuple errors on 5 parameters in asp.net mvc razor view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, tuples

I have no clue why I am getting this error.  I have done multi tuple controls before, but when I go to 5 I get this error.  What am I missing?

```
Compiler Error Message: CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements.

    Source Error:
    
    Line 78:     
    Line 79:     
    Line 80:     public class _Page_Views_Shared_Controls_MetaInput_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<(int Index {
```

**MetaInput.cshtml**

```
@model (int Index, MetaModel Field, List<MetaModel> FieldList, string Prefix, string ClassName)
```

**Calling Page**

```
 @Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views.Controls.MetaInput, (field.Index, field.Item, Model.Meta, "Players", "table-col-md"))
```

Comment: Can you show the server side code behind code?

Comment: There is nothing under the @model of the control.  You're right, when it hits 5 it errors, odd!